# Scala spark how do I sum two columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+------+-----+
|  ColA| ColB|
+------+-----+
|    5 |    1| 
|    8 |    2| 
+------+-----+
```

I need to add a summary column that ads the row values together like this:

```
+------+-----+-----+
|  ColA| ColB| SUM |
+------+-----+-----+
|    5 |    1|    6|
|    8 |    2|   10|
+------+-----+-----+
```

Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
var foo = df.withColumn("SUM", sum(df("ColA"), df("ColB")))
```

But I'm getting `error: overloaded method value sum with alternatives:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be as follow

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.function._

val data = List((1,5), (4,3), (6,2))
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("ColA", "ColB")

var foo = df.select("ColA", "ColB")
    .withColumn("SUM", col("ColA") + col("ColB"))
foo.show()
/*
+----+----+---+
|ColA|ColB|SUM|
+----+----+---+
|   1|   5|  6|
|   4|   3|  7|
|   6|   2|  8|
+----+----+---+
*/
// or

var foo2 = df.selectExpr(
    "ColA",
    "ColB",
    "ColA + ColB as SUM"
  )
foo2.show()
/*
+----+----+---+
|ColA|ColB|SUM|
+----+----+---+
|   1|   5|  6|
|   4|   3|  7|
|   6|   2|  8|
+----+----+---+
*/
```

Comment: I went with the first way, and it worked perfectly. Thanks!! Where is this in the documentation? I searched and didn't find this.

Comment: Hi @b-ryce, you're welcome. For Spark 2.4 https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/index.html, API for the question https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$, and Dataframes https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset